# postgres: how to execute script inside a .sql file

Tags: postgresql

In SQLite you can do

```
sqlite3 i.db < x.sql
```

where `x.sql` is a `create table` statement and `i.db` is the database

What is the equivalent in PostgreSQL ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also I think this post is more something for dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default command line tool for Postgres is `psql` it supports command line parameters to specify the database and a script name:

```
psql -d db_name -f x.sql
```

For details (e.g. how to specify the database user you want to use for the connection) see the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 2):

With a similar approach:

```
psql -U your_role your_db < x.sql
```

Within psql:

```
\i /path/to/x.sql
```